# Jstree adjust vertical gap between nodes

Tags: jstree

How to reduce the vertical gap between nodes with jstree?
The distance between nodes must be specified in a css file.
The icons used have a size of 12 x 12 pixels.

Attached sample of html code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>jstree</title>
            <style>
                html { margin:0; padding:0; font-size:45.5%; }
                body { max-width:800px; min-width:300px; margin:0 auto; padding:20px 10px; font-size:14px; font-size:1.4em; }
                h1 { font-size:2.8em; }
            </style>
            

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>jstree</h1>
            <div id="frmt" class="demo"></div>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.15/jstree.min.js"></script>
            
            <script>

            // data format demo "jstree-file"
            $('#frmt').jstree({
                'core' : {
                    'data' : [
                        {
                            "text" : "Root 1",
                            "icon" : "./icon12px-12px.png",
                            "state" : { "opened" : true,"selected" : true },
                            "children" : [
                                {
                                    "text" : "Child node 11",
                                    "icon" : "./icon12px-12px.png"
                                },
                                {   "text" : "Child node 12", 
                                    "icon" : "./icon12px-12px.png",
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
            });

            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```